# Wamp Server not getting all post data

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, wamp

I created a large form where user can set permission for different user group for role based system.

it list all the modules available in system in one column

next 6 columns show different checkbox for permissions ('View','ADD','EDIT','Retore'...)

so it become a very large form.

if i check all check boxes and submit it is not sending all data to server. so in db it is not saved
(it is working fine on other ubuntu pc which use common database).

If i uncheck above row and select below one it get selected also get saved to database.

i tried googling but not worked

**I Increased `post_max_size` to 2000M in php.ini**

**Some post was saying to increase `memory_limit` changed to 2000M in php.ini**

**also checked improper starting and closing of tags around form tag.**

**var_dump($_POST); also showing truncated data. :'(**

> system configuration is window 8.1 pro,
>
> wamp server 2.2 64bit,
>
> php 5.3.13
>
> apache 2.2.22
>
> php Application in Codeigniter 2.1

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Comment: there are 9 columns ans 153 rows of checkboxes, and 4 input field with a submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're hitting the limit of input variables (`max_input_vars`). You need to increase that value to suit your application. I believe it defaults to 1000 and you're over it (9*153+4)

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

Read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars).

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem . I just had to enable the mod_rewrite.
      This is how I solved it.
http://postimg.org/image/cwyr380zp

Comment: thanks but it is already enabled